# Display Cross-domain feed RSS in Wordpress site

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I need to display cross-domain feeds-rss (XML format)in my site, but i get a error because ajax cross-domain call are not allowed. I've been told about json-p...anyone knows how to use or have some good tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest way is just to create an widget for wordpress or download some kind of like your requirement.

Because `json-p` load data in `JSON` format if you want to get data from `JSON` format then the given link will help you :

[getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)
[ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

or you can access the rss feed with php like given example :

```
$xml = 'http://blog.webtech11.com/feed';
                $doc = new DOMDocument();
                $doc->load($xml);
                $item = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');

                //$data = array();

                for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++){
                    $title = $item->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
                    $link = $item->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
                    echo '<a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank"><h2>' . $title . '</h2></a>';
                }
```

in this example i access latest 4 blog entries..

hope this will help you

Comment: i just cannot understand what does $data = array(); i deleted it and it's still working fine

Comment: @user1367436 OOPS! sorry i tried something else, and forget to remove this ;)