# how to save images from RSS in wordpress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

my english is week so if u find difficulty in understanding then i apologize in advance.

**Problem :** i am writing XML from RSS and importing it to wordpress, in that RSS i have images with each item, i want to store image name,link in wordpress with posts,

tried many tutorials like [This](http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/the-wordpress-extended-rss-wxr-exportimport-xml-document-format-decoded-and-explained/) but i am unable to find a way to import images aswell, i have all images in a directory,

where i should keep them(images) in wordpress and how to save their names alongwith posts,

if this question needs editing then please edit it.

Once again Many thanks!

Comment: take a look on the given link hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811065/display-cross-domain-feed-rss-in-wordpress-site/10811457#10811457

Comment: i am able to import my xml into wordpress using `RSS Importer` plugin, i just need to know wot to do with images ?

Comment: above link describes how we get RSS feeds, my question is specifically about images with posts

Comment: interested in knowing this too.